Time-oriented Lorentzian manifolds
I am reading Lorentzian geometry on my own. We  say a Lorentzian manifold $M$ is a pair $(M,g)$ where $M$ is a  smooth manifold of dimension $(n+1)$ and $g$ is Lorentz metric such that $g$ assigns for each $p\in M$ a nondegenerate symmetric bilinear form $g_p$ of index $1$ on $T_pM$.
A nonzero tangent vector $v$ is timelike (resp. lightlike, spacelike) if $g_p(v, v)$ is negative (resp. null, positive). In each tangent space, the
set of lightlike vectors is a cone, called the lightcone, with two connected components.
A Lorentzian manifold M is $\textbf{time-orientable}$ if it is possible to make a continuous choice, in each tangent space, of one of the connected components of the lightcone.
can I define $\textbf{time-orientable}$ as follows?
Let $M$ be a Lorentzian manifold and $\mathscr{P}(TM)$ denotes the power set of the tangent bundle. A. time-orientation of $M$ is a map $\zeta:  M \rightarrow \mathscr{P}(TM)$. such that for all $p\in M$,

$\zeta(p)$ is one of the connected components of T_pM$

There is a chart $(U; x_o, \cdots, x_n)$ of $p$ such that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_o} \Big|_q \in \zeta(q)$ for all. $q\in U$.


$M$ is time-orientable if it admits a time-orientation $\zeta$.
Am I right?

this looks correct

Does this not imply that there are coordinates such that $g_{00}=0$? I am not exactly sure this true...
